# C# JSON Post From JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, json, null

I have the following 2 classes which hold the data:

```
public class ItemList{
    public IList<Item> Items{get;set;}
}

public class Item{
    public int id {get;set}
    public string name {get;set}
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
 public virtual JsonResult SaveItems(ItemList items)
    {}
```

I try to post a JS object like this:

```
var toPost = { "items" : [ {"id" : 1, "name":"test}, {"id" : 1, "name":"test"}] }


   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "URL TO POST TO",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: toPost,
                        traditional: true,
                        success: function (data, status, request) {
                            if (data.Error != undefined) {
                                alert("System Error: " + data.Error);

                                return;
                            }
                            console.log("Success");

                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            console.log("ERROR");
                        }
                    });
```

I do a `console.log` before i post it and the data looks as desribed in the `toPost` variable but when debugging on C# side the `ItemList items` is null

Comment: try items with capital I (different in your class and json string)

Comment: where is the content type attr ?

Comment: Its dataType: "json" i use

Comment: datatype is for the reponse. you need contenttype

Comment: The `I` in `Items` needs to be capital, you need the `_contentType` attribute.

Comment: Does the _contentType in the Ajax call?

Comment: You're missing quotation marks on the toPost variable, fyi.

Answer (score 3):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) in toPost and set the content type

```
$.ajax({
                    ...
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    data: JSON.stringify(toPost),
                    ...
});
```

Comment: When you stringify it is then a string.. So why is context type JSON and not string?

Comment: stringify serializes the object into a JSON string so that it can be transmitted to the server. Content type is for the server to know what  the string is - it can be JSON, query string, XML, etc.

Comment: HTTP doesn't understand JSON. Json is an object notation, not an object in it's own right. So from a HTTP point of view your just sending a string to the server. The server though does understand Json and it knows that if your sending a request with a content type of JSON then the string in the request can be serialised from JSON into an object.

Comment: BTW if your planning on supporting older browsers then I'd [recommend using the json2 library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736152/json2-library-required-still)

Comment: @Liam You **can** send plain javavscript object to the server it's just that the server wont be able to convert it to json and produce structure. you can read the content via ` new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()` There youll see something like `id=1&name=33`. ( im not saying you should , just saying you can)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, No, you cannot send a javascript object across **HTTP**. HTTP is a text based protocol. The server may interpret that text as an object but you need to seperate the server process and the communication protocol. Javascript writes to the protocol not to the server.

Comment: @Liam You can ( im not saying you should) .(http://i.stack.imgur.com/C9yRw.jpg). but it will be very hard to deal with it. ( using fiddler you can see the text in more readble way -http://i.stack.imgur.com/tC9R1.png)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, `t` in that example is a string?!! It's not an object, javascript or C#. You still need to parse that string into an object. HTTP only allows the sending of name/value (`name=value&name=value`) pairs of strings(full stop)

Comment: `t` in the server side is a string. ( ReadToEnd() returns string). and yes -- this string is not an object. and i still need to parse it(painfull). but you said : _you cannot send a javascript object across HTTP_ which is not accurate. i did send a plain JS object which was converted to string (which i read via stream) which is attached to a posted key value . how i got it on the other side ? that's another story. and it is sent via key value. its just that the value is very hard to parse

Comment: @RoyiNamir The object was sent because JQuery converted it into a query string before _sending_ it to the server. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. "Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string."

Comment: @LostInComputer Yes I know that. I just stated that the OP can send objects to the server. (jquery will convert it to string / Json.stringify).

Answer (score 0):

Your SaveItems method is expecting an ItemsList object and what is being sent in the request is a string. You will need to deserialise the request data into your ItemsList object something like the following:

```
public virtual JsonResult SaveItems(String jsonRequest)
{
    ItemsList items = Util.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ItemsList>(jsonRequest);

    // further processing of items
}
```

Comment: @lordkain not default. you should add reference to `System.Web.Extensions.dll`